# Cannot locate Java class

Tags: java

**Hello everyone,**

Basically, I am now starting to learn Java, using various websites such as w3schools, I started using Notepad++ and Command Prompt as I've used Command Prompt previously for Ubuntu. I ran a simple hello world piece of code and found that it cannot find my class. I set a CLASSPATH, however to no avail, no classes were found there. I really need help as I can't find where any of my classes were (I am able to set my CLASSPATH though)

Command Prompt

[image: Command Prompt]

Directory (I thought it was in)

[image: Directory]

If someone could help me find where my classes are or explain how to locate them or if there is another problem I don't see, that would be greatly appreciated.

- Knownfull

Comment: `Folder (I Thought it was in)` So where is the file?

Comment: You should launch the _javac_ command in the same folder where is your class file. The _CLASSPATH_ variable is not needed in this case. That varialbe, contains a list of folders and java archive filed that contains compiled classes.

Comment: Just copy and paste your images directly on the site... gyazo is blocked for some people...

Comment: Also, avoid using w3schools, see: https://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Try to download IJ idea or eclipse or netbeens. It will solve many time for you. Working with java around 9 years, still have no idea how to compile files from command prompt.

Comment: The file is expected to be in the directory you are executing `javac` from. So `C:\Users\rolly` in your case.

Comment: You are setting classpath to a file, not a directory, which is never going to work. If indeed you actually did create class files, you can find them by going to the directory you were in when you ran javac and running `dir /s *.class`, but IMHO your best next step is to install IntelliJ Community Edition and use that.

Comment: Thank you everyone who answered, I have figured out to fix some of those problems, however have come to the problem of:

https://i.gyazo.com/57e49bd108c9c8f2c0d976e7d446dbf1.png
( Can't copy the image directly for some odd reason, sorry, hopefully that makes it clearer than my last message.)

Comment: Nvm, fixed all of the issues and it works Great! Thank you for all your time and help, greatly appreciated, now I'll go and learn java! :). Have a good day! - Btw for anyone wondering, my problem was that my java folder I was editing in notepad was not named the same as the class, which I had fixed, then I moved it from desktop to a folder I created in C:\, in which I had then javac MyClass.java and it had worked (Name of folder)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i sort of solved my class path annoyance, to actually run the .class  files (java *namehere*).

You need to setup a specific folder for your x.java and x.class files.
For this example i'll use "C:\Users\rafhe\Documents".
You now need to go to your system tab and find the option for advanced system configurations, which may vary but in windows 10 you simply need to search for System and there's gonna be a text option for "Advanced System Options/configurations".
Once you click it you'll open a new tab, click ambient variations.
On user variables, create a new one named CLASSPATH.
Name it CLASSPATH and use whatever directory you need.(I'm using documents)
Now use this folder to setup your .class and .java files.
This should work to do stuff in the command prompt like:
java Example

I hope i'm not missing anything, since nowhere have this problem been properly adressed. Remember to setup your PATH too.